# How to create centeralized auth server for multiple micro services in docker

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework

I am running single django project as a micro service in docker, so i am running mutiple django projects for multiple micro services in docker,  and I am able to setting up auth server (oauth or jwt), user management to each micro service individually.

is this possible to create single auth server(user management, permissions) for multiple micro services in a docker.

If it is possible to create single auth server, then how API's get permissions from the auth server.

Comment: consider checking https://www.keycloak.org, it might be used a container that cares about auth needs, so everybody is authorized or authenticated there, and in your services you need only to verify jwt signture.

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways you can do that depending on what you need and how big is the load on your apps. You can create an auth server that your client will call for authentication and your microservices will call it for authorization when a request for a resource is made.

Read this article for a more detailed view in order to see what suits you best.
https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/microservice-authentication-and-authorization-solutions-e0e5e74b248a